# Why I'm getting diff node.js versions reported?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code, just noticed I'm getting two different versions of Node.js from powershell, and About.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the version from vscode is 'the node version of vscode', you know the vscode is developed by `Typescript`.

And the version from powershell is your own node version you installed.

Comment: Interesting. But why do they need to list out what version of Node is used? What's the purpose?

Comment: @Jeb50 I don't know the real reason. I guess the vscode is based on Electron, for some developers, they can use [Microsoft/vscode-node-debug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-node-debug) to debug vscode, providing the node version will facilitate it.